# Using Visual Studio IDE for JavaScript development in SharePoint - files renaming automatically to MyFile.js~RFxxxxx.TMP

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, sharepoint, ide, rename

I am trying to use Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 for developing JavaScript files in SharePoint (both on-premise & 365). Visual Studio seems to change the file name during the save process a couple of time, and this causes some problems:

Ex: Suppose I have an html file with a reference to Myfile.Js as following:

```
<script src="/sites/MyTestSite/TheLibrary/MyFile.js">
```

When I open & save MyFile.Js in VS, VS first renames it to MyFile.js~RF79854ax46.TMP. Then SharePoint automatically updates the reference in html file to the following:

```
<script src="/sites/MyTestSite/TheLibrary/MyFile.js~RF79854ax46.TMP">
```

I was wondering how can I either disable this feature of Visual Studio or SharePoint! Never had such problem with NotePad++, which is very simple & nice editor.

Any help would be appreciated!

P.S
Disabling autorecover options didn't work.
I have tested with Adobe DreamWeaver as well, the same problem.
It seems this issue had existed in earlier versions of SharePoint as well,([link to MS support](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/96e88bf9-62ea-4415-bcf3-6a0fdcdedb02/kb2550581-fcb-problems-may-also-cause-other-kinds-of-nonresponsiveness-including-some?forum=w7itproperf)) , but no results for SharePoint online.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2013 renaming files to .TMP has nothing to do with SharePoint. It is a Visual Studio issue. Normally Visual Studio creates .TMP files so it can recover files after an unexpected crash. Make sure you have installed the latest update to Visual Studio 2013. You kan also try install VS 2015 and the latest update.

To turn off the autorecover feature in VS 2013 or VS 2015 go to Tools > Options > Environment > AutoRecover and uncheck 'Save AutoRecovery information every:'.

The issue can also be caused by virus protecting tools like F-Secure, Microsoft Security Essentials, etc. Go thrugh the tool settings and add Visual Studio Project folder to exclusion list and/or set *.vb and *.cs extensions to exlusion list.

Comment: Thanks Xaphod, but how can I disable this functionality of Visual Studio? sometimes in some environment? I have the latest updates for VS.

Comment: To turn off the autorecover feature in VS 2013 or VS 2015 go to Tools > Options > Environment > AutoRecover and uncheck 'Save AutoRecovery information every:'. (Answer updated)

Comment: Hi Patrick A! Could you please click the Answer button for this answer if it was helpful for you?

Comment: Yes Xaphod! I plan to do it today! Thanks :-)

Comment: Xaphod, this didn't work. I disabled the AutoRecovery  options as you said, but the same result. VS created this MyFile2.js~RF3c54874b.TMP again.

Comment: updated answer with virus protecting tools exlusions.

Comment: Disabling antivirus didn't work either. Considering the fact the files are on Microsoft 365 cloud, not local..

Comment: What happens if you create a brand new Project from Visual Studio, do you get the same issue? What if you place Projects on different locations, like one on C: and another Project on D:?

Comment: As I said, this happens only in SharePoint 365. Of course this will happen when you save it in local folder, but the temporary file will be deleted wuite fast and user does not notify anything. But when you are in an environment like SharePoint 365 which renaming files even for 1 ms will affect other files, then you got this issue.

Comment: So I can reproduce the issue, could you please provide a short description of how you set up your project in Office 365?

Comment: Update: I have tested the issue with DreamWeaver as well. . When you modify the file and press save, the produce ~RFxxxxx.TM files.
I found this as well, which seems that SharePoint has had this issue earlier: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/96e88bf9-62ea-4415-bcf3-6a0fdcdedb02/kb2550581-fcb-problems-may-also-cause-other-kinds-of-nonresponsiveness-including-some?forum=w7itproperf